# Understanding the semantics behind the code

Tags: ocaml, coq

I have an OCaml code, and I have a hard time to formalize the function `mi_pol` into Coq because I am not understand clearly what exactly this code working, for example at the

```
aux (vec_add add const (vector ci v)) args ps
```

and

```
args.(i-1) <- mat_add add args.(i-1) (matrix ci m); aux const args ps
```

and

```
aux (vec_0 z dim) (Array.make n (mat_0 z dim)) ps
```

This is the code:

```
let vector = List.map;;

let clist x =
  let rec aux k = if k <= 0 then [] else x :: aux (k-1) in aux;;

let vec_add add v1 v2 =
  try List.map2 add v1 v2
  with Invalid_argument _ ->
    error_fmt "sum of two vectors of different size";;

let mat_add add m1 m2 =
  try List.map2 (vec_add add) m1 m2
  with Invalid_argument _ ->
    error_fmt "sum of two matrices of different size";;

(*vector zero *)
let vec_0 z dim = clist z dim;;  

(* matrix zero *)
let mat_0 z dim = clist (vec_0 z dim) dim;;
let comp f g x = f (g x);;

(* matrix transpose *)
let transpose ci =
  let rec aux = function
    | [] | [] :: _ -> []
    | cs -> List.map (comp ci List.hd) cs :: aux (List.map List.tl cs)
  in aux;;  

(* matrix *)
let matrix ci m =
  try transpose ci m
  with Failure _ -> error_fmt "ill-formed matrix";;

let mi_pol z add ci =
  let rec aux const args = function
    | [] -> { mi_const = const; mi_args = Array.to_list args }
    | Polynomial_sum qs :: ps -> aux const args (qs @ ps)
    | Polynomial_coefficient (Coefficient_matrix [v]) :: ps
    | Polynomial_coefficient (Coefficient_vector v) :: ps ->
      aux (vec_add add const (vector ci v)) args ps
    | Polynomial_product [p] :: ps -> aux const args (p :: ps)
    | Polynomial_product [Polynomial_coefficient (Coefficient_matrix m); 
                          Polynomial_variable i] :: ps ->
      args.(i-1) <- mat_add add args.(i-1) (matrix ci m);
      aux const args ps
    | _ -> not_supported "todo"
  in fun dim n -> function
    | Polynomial_sum ps -> aux (vec_0 z dim) (Array.make n (mat_0 z dim)) ps
    | _ -> not_supported
      "todo";;
```

Any help is very appreciate. If you can have a Coq code for `mi_pol` it will help me a lot.

Comment: This question is very badly ask. You admit to not even understanding the code, yet you want to formalize it? I think you got the cart before the horse.

Comment: Voted for close as "too localised" - unlikely to help any future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to take a polynomial on a vector space, and compute the sum of all the (transpose of) (matrix) coefficients attached to each variable. `args` is an array such that `args.(i)` is the sum of all coefficients on the `i`-th variable, and `const` the sum of constant scalars.

I don't know what's the meaning of this operation, but I suspect it doesn't mean much in the general case (working over arbitrary products of sums of products of ...; that would lead to strange non-linear/homogeneous behaviors). I suppose there are implicit constraints on what the shape of actual values of this polynomial type are, for example it may be linear in all variables.